# How to create a function that accepts n- number of parameters and returns objects accordingly

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, oop

I want to create a class and a function that accepts any number of parameters 
(it can be an array too).

What I want to achieve is, I want to pass all parameters required for the stored proc and their data type and it should return them as `SqlParameter` array

**DAL CODE**

```
public DataSet createProblemStatement()
        {
            DataSet createProblemStatement = SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(CCSVas.Constants.ConnectionString.DBConnection, "usp_ProblemStatements_Add", ProblemStatement.createProblemStatement("d", "d", "d", "d", "d"));
             return createProblemStatement;

        }
```

**Function that will assign values**

```
public static SqlParameter[] createProblemStatement(string strProblemTitle, string strProblemOwner, string strBusinessPurpose, string strProblemDescription, string strAssociateId) {
            SqlParameter ProblemTitle = new SqlParameter();
            ProblemTitle.DbType = DbType.String;
            ProblemTitle.Value = strProblemTitle;
            ProblemTitle.ParameterName = "@strProblemTitle";
             SqlParameter ProblemOwner = new SqlParameter();
            ProblemOwner.DbType = DbType.String;
            ProblemOwner.Value = strProblemOwner;
            ProblemOwner.ParameterName = "@strProblemOwner";
            SqlParameter BusinessPurpose = new SqlParameter();
            BusinessPurpose.DbType = DbType.String;
            BusinessPurpose.Value = strBusinessPurpose;
            BusinessPurpose.ParameterName = "@strBusinessPurpose";
             SqlParameter ProblemDescription = new SqlParameter();
            ProblemDescription.DbType = DbType.String;
            ProblemDescription.Value = strBusinessPurpose;
            ProblemDescription.ParameterName = "@strProblemDescription";
             SqlParameter AssociateId = new SqlParameter();
            AssociateId.DbType = DbType.String;
            AssociateId.Value = strBusinessPurpose;
            AssociateId.ParameterName = "@strAssociateId";

            SqlParameter[] createProblemStatement = { ProblemTitle, ProblemOwner, BusinessPurpose, ProblemDescription, AssociateId };

            return createProblemStatement;

        }
```

The issue i have with this function is, **this will only accept defined parameters and is not reusable**

Comment: Pass a dictionary with column name as key and column value as value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a helper class that let you construct the Parameter array in a controlled fashion without being stuck with a method implementation for each case.

First create a class for the Extension methods for List

```
// helper for Adding parameters to a list
public static class SqlParameters
{  
    // or have strongly typed overloads
    public static List<SqlParameter> Add(
        this List<SqlParameter> list, 
        string paramName, 
        object value)
    {  
        var p =new SqlParameter(
                    paramName, 
                    Map(value.GetType()));
        p.Value = value;
        list.Add(p);
        return list;
    }

    private static DbType Map(Type type)
    {
        DbType dbtype = DbType.Object;
        if (type == typeof(System.String))
        {
            dbtype = DbType.String;
        }
        if (type == typeof(System.Int32))
        {
            dbtype = DbType.Int32;
        }
        return dbtype;
    }
}
```

Then use that in a Builder for your parameters:

```
// builder
public class ProblemStatement
{
    List<SqlParameter> list = new List<SqlParameter>();

    // single parameter
    public ProblemStatement Title(string value)
    {
       list.Add("strProblemTitle", value);
       return this;
    }
    public ProblemStatement Owner(string value)
    {
       list.Add("strProblemOwner", value);
       return this;
    }
    public ProblemStatement Description(string value)
    {
       list.Add("strProblemOwner", value);
       return this;
    }
    // a couple of parameters together at once...
    public ProblemStatement AddProblem(string title, 
                                       string owner, 
                                       string description)
    {
       return Title(title)
              .Owner(owner)
              .Description(description); // re-use methods
    }

    public SqlParameter[] ToArray()
    {
        return list.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Usage of the Builder:

```
DataSet createProblemStatement = SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(
       CCSVas.Constants.ConnectionString.DBConnection, 
       "usp_ProblemStatements_Add", 
       new ProblemStatement().Title("d")
                             .Owner("d")
                             .Description("d")
                             .ToArray());
 return createProblemStatement;
```

Notice that you can define as many parameters you like in the builder without having to specify and or use them.

Answer (score 2):

Use **params**  keyword.By using the params keyword, you can specify a method parameter that takes a variable number of arguments.

[params (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db.aspx)

Comment: can this be a two dimensional array??

Comment: pass object and then by using reflection you can fill SqlParameter array

Answer (score 2):

If you using Dot net Framwork 4.0+ then use `dynamic` other wise use `object`.

Below is code snippet.

```
public static SqlParameter[] createProblemStatement(params dynamic[] test)
{
    var lstParam = new List<SqlParameter>();

    foreach (var item in test)
    {
        var paramType = item.GetType();
        if (paramType == typeof(string))
        {
            //Do something.
            lstParam.Add(obj);
        }
        else if (paramType == typeof(int))
        {
            //Do something.
            lstParam.Add(obj);
        }

    }
    return lstParam.ToArray();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `params` keyword to get the "indeterminate length" functionality then just pass `SqlParameters`

```
public DataSet CreateProblemStatement(params SqlParamter[] paremeters)
{
    DataSet createProblemStatement = SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(CCSVas.Constants.ConnectionString.DBConnection, "usp_ProblemStatements_Add", paremeters);
     return createProblemStatement;

}
```

Which you would call like this:

```
var problemTitle = new SqlParameter("@strProblemTitle", "Some Title");
var problemOwner = new SqlParameter("@strProblemOwner", "Owner Name");
...
var result = CreateProblemStatement(problemTitle, problemOwner, businessPurpose, problemDescription, associateId);
```